# Installing custom sAPOs swap sample in Windows, using INFs

Tags: windows, audio

I am trying to install the Swap sample in an end-user system. This is one of the "audio system
effects" samples provided by Microsoft at this [[link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463044.aspx).

I want to do this installation using the sysfx.inf file found at location C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\audio\sysfx\Inf.
But the readme file for these samples mentions only about the steps required for testing without INFs. For the end-user system 
I cannot go for this manual approach.

Kindly inform me about the procedure or any documentation, for installing this sample with making use of the INFs.

Also, please inform me how to apply PUMASecure-Off.reg to these samples.